# Undo route "reject"?

Tags: ubuntu, route

I ran this command to "block" an IP address:

```
route add -host 123.123.123.123 reject
```

It works. I can see it in the list of routes:

```
root@mypc:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
123.123.123.123 -               255.255.255.255 !H    0      -        0 -
```

Cool. How do I delete the route?

I tried:

```
root@mypc:~# route del 123.123.123.123 gw - netmask 255.255.255.255 metric 0
```

But it gave this (error?):

```
-: Unknown host
```

How do I delete a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the original command but with `delete` instead of `add`:

```
route delete -host 123.123.123.123 reject
```